# Shorten menu links in left-side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website with a left-side menu. The width of the menu is 200px in every media query. Our clients can add pages using our CMS and sometimes use very long menu-item-names.

When a link is too long you can scroll horizontally in the menu-holder with is ugly!

Is there somebody who can tell me how to shorten those links to max 16 characters and make them end with: `...`

Other solutions are also welcome of course!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: I can't accept your comment als an answer because it's à comment Rory McCrossan. Your answer is definetly the solution to my problem!

Comment: I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS alone to solve this problem using the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property. Try this:

```
li {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden; /* this must be anything other than visible */
}
```

[MDN docs: text-overflow](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

You may also need to set a `width` on the element, but that is down to your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : shortend names inside `ul` menu with fullname title

```js
window.onload = function(){

var names = document.getElementById('names');
var name = names.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0 ; i< name.length ; i++){
name[i].title = name[i].textContent;
if(name[i].textContent.length > 16){
name[i].textContent = name[i].textContent.substring(0,16)+'...';
}
}
}
```

```css
ul{
padding:0;
width:200px;
}
li{
text-align:center;
display:block;
padding:10px;
font-size:20px;
border-bottom:solid 2px orange;
color:orange;
word-wrap:break-word;
cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<ul id="names">
<li>Ahmed saeed Ali Mustafa Mohamed</li>
<li>Mamdouh Mustafa</li>
<li>Ali Mohamed Hussien</li>
<li>Mohamed Abu-trika</li>
<li>Yasser Yousef</li>
</ul>
```